# What is the difference between creating UIViewController instance in implmentation and interface file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, properties

Its kinda general question. What difference it make if we create instance of UIViewController in interface (*.h) file and declare it as property and use it in implementation (*.m) file to push it on current view  than that of creating instance in implmentation file itself and push it on current view in UINavigationcontroller ?

Regards,
Sumit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Interface i.e. .h file we are just having declaration of the variables and that are only the references to the class and NOT the INSTANCE... Please understand the difference between reference and instance both are different. When declaring in .h file we are agreeing that we are going to use that variable in our .m file. And we can instanciate it... Also other 2 answers are also having its own points....

Answer (score 1):

Usually you define your `UIViewController` in .h as a field of your @interface because you may need to access it in more than one point or it can be useful, for you, to keep a pointer to that controller. If you don't need this you can simply define it in .m, use it and then release (or autorelease) it.

Comment: Thanks a lot.... I have this grid of button who has background image on each of them. After you tap on these button it will push a viewController in it which will help me to display that large scale image. I was also thinking of putting toolbar down on that view which I can use for traversing through adjacent button background images. Which for sure will require UIViewController declared in interface file I guess. is that right ?

Comment: Well, for how you described it seems you don't have a real need to keep a pointer to that controller after it has been pushed, so maybe you can simply create it in .m without defining it as a property. I may have misunderstood your needs, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few differences. By making it a property the code generated will have some retain/release logic built in.

Also, by declaring the field and property in your .H file, the member is effectively "public" and visible now from other classes. If you only have the member defined in your .M file, it is only accessible within your own class.

Comment: Thanks a lot.... I have this grid of button who has background image on each of them. After you tap on these button it will push a viewController in it which will help me to display that large scale image. I was also thinking of putting toolbar down on that view which I can use for traversing through adjacent button background images. Which for sure will require UIViewController declared in interface file I guess. is that right ?